# URL access from web page

Tags: python

I am not able to access all the URLs from bing.com web page I am using this program .

```
def main():
    usock = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/")
    parser = urllister.URLLister()
    parser.feed(usock.read())
    usock.close() 
    parser.close() 
    for url in parser.urls:
        print url
```

I will get only few URLs which are written in HTML,
Is it possible to get the all the URLs of a web page from source page ?  or are there any restrictions to access these URLs, can anybody please check and lemme know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
def urllist():
    import urllib2
    import re
    website = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
    html = website.read()
    links = re.findall('"((?:http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
    for link in links:
        print link
```

This might help.

Comment: `"((?:http|ftp)s?://.*?)"` won't catch just `http` and `ftp` words

Comment: What does that means **won't catch just words**.

Comment: without `?:` you will get \('http://schema.org/WebPage', 'http'\), if you add `?:` you will get only link 'http://schema.org/WebPage'. regex key `?:` meaning "don't catch this group". You can run your code with `?:` and without it and you will see difference

Comment: Ok I see your point, it was a requirement previously in one of my codes so I didn't bother to modify it much but you're right about regex key. My bad Please see I've updated it with new one.

Answer (score 2):

```
import httplib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


http = httplib2.Http()

status, response = http.request('http://www.bing.com/')


for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):

    if link.has_attr('href'):

        print link['href']
```

try with beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

`lxml` lib example:

```
from lxml.html import parse

page = parse('http://bing.com').getroot()
for l in page.iterlinks():
    if l[2].startswith('http'):
        print(l[2])
```

From `lxml` lib doc:

> .iterlinks():
>
> This yields (element, attribute, link, pos) for every link in the document. attribute may be None if the link is in the text (as will be the case with a `<style>` tag with @import).
> This finds any link in an action, archive, background, cite, classid, codebase, data, href, longdesc, profile, src, usemap, dynsrc, or lowsrc attribute. It also searches style attributes for url(link), and `<style>` tags for @import and url().
> This function does not pay attention to `<base href>`.